# WinSCP - Is there any way to reset or remove the master password?

Tags: ftp, password-recovery, winscp

For the life of me I can't remember what the master password is and there seems to be no option to reset or remove it without knowing it.

Obviously the master password is used to encrypt the FTP passwords, so resetting or removing it would clear those. That's fine, I can enter them again after setting a new one. I just miss the convenience of not having to enter them every time.

Answer (score 2):

WinSCP has no option to remove/reset master password.

You have to do it manually in Registry by setting:

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Martin Prikryl\WinSCP 2\Configuration\Security]
"UseMasterPassword"=dword:00000000
```

Of course, you lose all your encrypted passwords.

You can then go to preferences again and set new master password. While doing that WinSCP will prompt you for previous master password once for every lost password. Just cancel those prompts with the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key.

See the documentation for handling [forgotten master password](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/master_password#reset).

Comment: A bit more explanation would help the OP and future users.

Comment: @Dave M: ok, done